# IE Error "Unexpected call to method or property access. Line: 113 Char: 460 Code: 0"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I've been having problems with IE 8 on my website using jQuery, where IE doesn't really give any specific error message, but none of the script gets executed.

Everything works fine in Firefox/Chrome, but when I load the website in IE, I get the not much saying `Unexpected call to method or property access. Line: 113 Char: 460 Code: 0`

I've tried to check my code with JSLint, but it didn't find any errors. Are there any specific things that might trigger this?

The application is quite AJAX heavy, you can get to it at http://hledammodelku.cz/

The gallery on the right side doesn't load in IE, because the javascript doesn't get executed.

Comment: Have you tried the IE8 developer tools debugger yet, at least to see the line of code causing the error?

Comment: Debugger ends up somewhere deep in jQuery code, where line 113 doesn't really say anything, as it is all minified.

Answer (score 0):

I may have seen something like this before (IE 6, 7, 8) whereby there was a stray comma at the end of an object literal, such as:

```
{ 
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    c: 9,
}
```

Could this be it?

Granted that JSLint should probably pick this up. I'm just offering a possible fix based on my own somewhat upsetting experiences with a similar issue!

I found a link from [jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/unexpected-call-to-method-or-property-access-in-ie8) on my travels that also fixed an issue like this.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful for you.

[JavaScript IE appendChild() - Unexpected call to method or property access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708698/javascript-ie-appendchild-unexpected-call-to-method-or-property-access)

PS. Read the whole thread and don't add the timeout as the first answer says!! :)