# Javascript appendChild Image IE error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, appendchild

I'm trying to customize a javascript autosuggest result display a bit, by showing an image next to every result. It works great, except in IE. This is the code I added:

```
var a = _b.DOM.cE("a", { href:"#" });
var pic = _b.DOM.cE("img",{src:"AutoSuggest/"+arr[i].id+".jpg",className:"float"}," ");
a.appendChild(pic);
```

Here's the `_b.DOM.cE` function:

```
if (typeof(_b.DOM) == "undefined")
    _b.DOM = {};

/* create element */
_b.DOM.cE = function ( type, attr, cont, html )
{
    var ne = document.createElement( type );
    if (!ne)
            return 0;

    for (var a in attr)
            ne[a] = attr[a];
    var t = typeof(cont);
    if (t == "string" && !html)
            ne.appendChild( document.createTextNode(cont) );
    else if (t == "string" && html)
            ne.innerHTML = cont;
    else if (t == "object")
            ne.appendChild( cont );
    return ne;
};
```

IE gives the error "Unexpected call to method or property access", exactly as described here: [JavaScript IE appendChild() - Unexpected call to method or property access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708698/javascript-ie-appendchild-unexpected-call-to-method-or-property-access)
One of the people that answered said that IE gives that error because of `<img ...></img>`,
which I indeed see in the HTML my result creates. It should of course be `<img ... />`. So how can I fix this? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's fairly hard to offer any help without knowing what `_b.DOM.cE` looks like. Are you modifying minified code?

Comment: @AndréDion Hi Andre, the code comes from http://www.brandspankingnew.net/specials/ajax_autosuggest/ajax_autosuggest_autocomplete.html, when I download it there is a non-midified version of the code. I will keep searching if I can get you the code without you having to download it... couldn't find it within a few seconds.

Comment: @AndréDion Got it, here you can see the code: http://pastebin.com/FHZBt2WB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `," "` from the end of the `img`-creation line.

What your code is doing is attempting to do:

```
theImageElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
```

While some browsers may allow and silently ignore this error, it is indeed an error and IE is *strictly speaking* correct to complain about it.

As an aside, HTML does *not* have self-closing tags. So `<img></img>` is indeed the "correct" HTML representation of an image element, however the `<img>` element is not allowed to have child nodes.

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly when removing the ," " part. Thank you again!